# Use find.range to get first row in a column

Tags: vba, excel

For simplicity let's say I have the following data:
- Column A contains a list of seats available on a plane (seats that are not occupied)
1A,1B,1C,1D,1E,1F,2A,2B,2C,etc

When a seat available is allocated to a passenger, I would like to find that seat and delete it from the list.

My code works for every seat that is **not the first seat in column A**, let's say a passenger wants seat 1A which is Cell(1,1) or Range("A1") when I use find.range I get row 2, therefore it continues available for other passengers when in fact it shouldn't.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Private Sub RemoveFromListSeatAllocated(seat As String)
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rng, As Range

Set sht = Sheets("This sheet")
Set rng = Range("A1:A192")

'FIND SEAT IN LIST OF SEATS AVAILABLE
With sht.rng
  Set where = .Find(what:=seat, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With

Set rng = Range("A" & where.Row)

'DELETE SEAT FOUND AND SHIFT UP 
sht.rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, a silly workaround is to simply have my seat_list_data starting down from cell A2 instead of A1, so here I have my problem solved, but.. this is bugging me hard! I'd like to understand why it can't find a value placed in the first row and if it's possible to sort it out with "FIND" for future uses.

Answer (score 2):

"What am I doing wrong here?"
You are not using `Option Explicit`, thus the code quality is going low on a level that it does not compile:

`Dim rng, As Range` - that should be a compiling error, the comma is not needed

`With sht.rng` - compiling error

`Set where = .Find(what:=seat, LookIn:=xlValues)` - what is `where` - compiling error

---

Advise - write `Option Explicit` on the top of your module, then Select "Debug>Compile" and see the errors you are getting. Try to work on them, until you are able to compile.